# How to properly call an MVC Controller with AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make an AJAX call to an MVC controller ActionResult that I have.  I have used ajax before but I am new to MVC.  I have an AJAX call in a separate .js file that is triggered in an on click event attached to one of the buttons in a view.  The AJAX call is being triggered as expected, but always returns with a "resource not found" error.  Code shown below:

View Button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Download Pictures" id="btnGetPics"/>
```

AJAX Call:

```
    var ajaxURL = 'MMRController/TestAjax';
    $('#btnGetPics').on('click',
        function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxURL,
                data: param = "this",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    console.log('firing ajax call');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    console.log('Error');
                    console.log(ex.responseText);
                    alert("Error downloading images.  Please contact IT.");
                }
            });
        });
```

ActionResult in Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TextAjax(string param)
        {
            return Json(param + " works", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
            <br><br>

            <b> Requested URL: </b>/MMR/MMRController/TestAjax<br><br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[HttpException]: A public action method &#39;MMRController&#39; was not found on controller &#39;MOHR.Controllers.MMRController&#39;.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use just   var ajaxURL = 'TestAjax';

Comment: The word "Controller" isn't part of the url even if it's part of the class, unless your class is named MMRControllerController. Try to access the url manually first. And the url should start with / if you specify the controller.

Comment: Try use url like this: var ajaxURL = '/MMR/TestAjax';

Comment: @sinitram this results in a new error: Invalid JSON primitive: this.

Comment: @the_lotus  After changing var ajaxURL = '/MMR/TestAjax' I am still getting "The resource cannot be found" as an error.  More specifically that a public action method TestAjax was not found on controller MOHR.Controllers.MMRController.

Comment: and it is because of data: param = "this", use data: { param : "this"}

Comment: Are you using an Area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do 3 things differently:

- Use the shorthand jQuery post `$.post` (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- Use `@Url.Action` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
- Format your data as valid JSON

  `var url = '@Url.Action("TestAjax","MMR")';`

  `// use this if you are using an MVC area
  // var url = '@Url.Action("TestAjax","MMRController", new { Area = "AreaNameGoesHere" })';`

  `$.post(url, { param: 'this' }, function(){
      // success callback
  }).fail(function(){
      // failed callback
  });`

Answer (score 3):

You aren't setting the `data` property correctly.

```
data: param = "this"
```

should be

```
data: { param : "this"},
```

Also yyour url needs to have a forward slash before the controller (`/`) and remove the word `controller` so in full...

```
var ajaxURL = '/MMR/TestAjax';

//... etc..

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxURL,
            data: { param : "this"},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('firing ajax call');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                console.log('Error');
                console.log(ex.responseText);
                alert("Error downloading images.  Please contact IT.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: @sinitram Looking at it I think they've set up the request like that incorrectly and posted different code...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    var ajaxURL = 'MMRController/TestAjax';
    data: param = "this",
```

with

```
var ajaxURL = '/MMR/TestAjax';
data: {param :"this"},
```